# See all subscriptions in the Azure organization

Tags: azure

I am global admin in our organization, but still I cannot see all subscriptions in our organization in the "Subscriptions" blade ("Show only subscriptions selected in theglobal subscriptions filter" is turned off).
Shouldn't I be able to see all subscriptions as a global admin?

Answer (score 0):

If you need subscription filtering to persist across all browser resource blades, you should always set the subscription filter in the **Settings or Directory + Subscriptions** pane.

**To set the global subscription filter:**

1. Open the **Settings or Directory + Subscriptions** pane.
2. Select the subscriptions drop-down list.
3. Select the subscriptions. You might need to use the filter option to see the desired subscriptions.

[image]

Still you Don't see a subscription? Then Switch directories and check if you are able to see the subscriptions

[image]

**Reference:** [Associate or add an Azure subscription to your Azure Active Directory tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory)

Comment: I have selected all subscriptions in the Directory + Subscriptions pane, but I still don't see the subscriptions that my colleagues have created. 

I know they exist, I asked one of my colleagues to send a screen copy of his list of subscriptions. He is also a global admin.

So, we only see the subscriptions we have created, although we are both global admins. 

Maybe this is the way it is supposed to work (i.e. you have to explicitly grant permissions for other people to see "your" subscriptions), but how in the world would then a global admin have control over all subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

To see the subscription that your colleague has created, as long as the two of you are in the same tenant,he has to grant you a role on that subscripton. This also applies to you.

When you create a subscription, you become the owner of the subscription. However, the role of service administrators or co-administrators can be assigned to other Global admins to help out with the governance of that subscription.

This can be a guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#classic-subscription-administrator-roles

Thank you